# How to detect and change ios app language using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to detect which language the user have for the device. Then I want to change the language to a different language the app will load appropriate images, strings, storyboards.

I used the following to detect the language:

```
let lang: String = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0] as String
```

However this will return "en" for me even my iOS simulator is set to Arabic language.

Based on Objective-C questions, I tried to do the following to change the language to Arabic:

```
NSUserDefaults.setValue("ar", forKey: "AppleLanguage")
```

But this issues an error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSUserDefaults 0x103daa350> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key AppleLanguage.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you made, compiler think you're trying to use KVO, setting the value "ar" to the property "AppleLanguage" of the NSUserDefaults class. Which doesn't exist.

Use `setObject:forKey:` instead of `setValue:forKey`:

```
NSUserDefaults.setObject(["ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguage") // First param is an array.
```

And I never coded in Swift, but don't you need to get the standard defaults `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` before updating anything in it?

Comment: setObject is better but setValue would work as well. Your second point solves the problem.

Comment: Did not work for me. The app did not change to RTL and when rerun the app the language returned by NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0] is always "en-US"

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question about detecting the current language on the device is

```
NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleLanguageCode)! as! String
```